# Angular can't find module when using tsconfig path

Tags: angular, angular-library

So I have a root folder with 2 projects and I am trying to access a library project from an app using Angular 12.  In my root tsconfig I have setup a path to an entry point in the library.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "downlevelIteration": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "importHelpers": true,
      "target": "es2015",
      "module": "es2020",
      "lib": [
        "es2018",
        "dom"
      ],
      "paths": {
        "components-lib": [
          "shared-angular-components/projects/components-lib/src/public-api.ts",
        ],
      }
    }
  }
```

When I attempt to build my app I get the error:  Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components-lib' in '/Users/scott/code/myproject/myapp/src/app'

The app's tsconfig is:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I verified the paths are correct and point to the public-api.ts entry point.

I can run from the app "npx tsc" and it does not give an errors so I think everything is ok from the Typescript point of view.

Am I missing something perhaps in an angular.json file or something small like that?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am also stuck with this.
I am working on the storybook library which is not reading modules from another library when using tsconfig path.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem: I have path alias in my lib which work fine when I build the lib, but it doesn't when I use the lib in an app.